# 2 rows in qrtz_scheduler_state for each cluster node

Tags: sql-server, spring, weblogic, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I have quartz setup with clustering.  Each of the quartz cluster node servers have two distinct entries in the qrtz_scheduler_state table.  I can't understand it.  Has anyone seen this?

More info:
Original configuration that has issue
Spring 3.0.3
Quartz 1.8.5
Weblogic 10.3.5
SQL Server 2005

New configuration that also has the issue
Spring 3.1.1
Quartz 2.1.5
Weblogic 10.3.5
SQL Server 2005

quarts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd">

<!-- Defining this bean starts the triggers -->
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="pendingTransactionJob" />
            <ref bean="assetJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="wfbisDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="wfbisTransactionManager" />
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />

    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />

    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="pendingTransactionService" value-ref="pendingTransactionService" />
            <entry key="assetService" value-ref="assetService" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">ClusteredScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">6</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">300000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pendingTransactionJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="pendingTransactionJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean name="pendingTransactionJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.wellsfargo.trust.message.ScheduledJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="serviceName" value="pendingTransactionService" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="assetJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="assetJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean id="assetJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.wellsfargo.trust.message.ScheduledJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="serviceName" value="assetService" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hello. I am also facing similar issue in Quartz 2.2.1 version. Most probably, it is to do with wrong configuration. Was this question resolved. Could the original poster please provide solution, if there is one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Delete table entries, restart the cluster and see if double entries are created again. It could happen that those entries were created but not deleted by some errors.

Comment: Thanks jddsantaella.  When I remove a node from the cluster, both entries actually go away.  As soon as I startup a new node, it adds 2 entries.  Bananas...

Comment: Review your configuration to be sure you did not set up two scheduler when you just need one. Please, add your quartz configuration to your question

Comment: Just one scheduler so far.  See quartz-config.xml.